# Авторизация в VPN и AD/ldap через HASP

Tags: администрирование, vpn, active-directory, ldap, ipsec

1. Есть Cisco держащая IPSec VPN-ы.
2. Есть LDAP, в которых есть пользователи. Планируется переход на AD

Сейчас все пользователи подключаются к VPN через ldap (логин, пароль, секретный ключ).
Задача: разделить пользователей на две группы. Одна большая как и сейчас авторизуется, вторая авторизуется в VPN,  а желательно и во всем домене через аппаратный ключ.

Вопрос - как и какими средствами это можно организовать?